# Pratical data science cookbook code python

Tags: python, networking, networkx

So, I'm trying to use an code form this book:

www.ebooks-it.net/ebook/practical-data-science-cookbook

It's this one:

[image]

[image]

I'm new to python so Im not sure that I'm useing it right. I tried to do it like this:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import networkx as nx
import unicodecsv as csv

path = pandas.read_csv("hero-network.csv", low_memory=False)

def graph_from_csv(path):
    graph = nx.Graph(name="Heroic Social Network")
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        for row in reader:
            graph.add_edge(*row)
    return graph.size()

graph_from_csv(data)
```

But I'm not getting the same output like in the book.

my output is:

```
TypeError: invalid file:                LITTLE, ABNER        PRINCESS ZANDA
0              LITTLE, ABNER  BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL
1       BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL        PRINCESS ZANDA
2              LITTLE, ABNER        PRINCESS ZANDA
3              LITTLE, ABNER  BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL
4       BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL        PRINCESS ZANDA
5       STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA      FORTUNE, DOMINIC
6       STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA   ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA
7       STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA  IRON MAN/TONY STARK 
8       STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA  IRON MAN IV/JAMES R.
9       STEELE, SIMON/WOLFGA  RAVEN, SABBATH II/EL
10      RAVEN, SABBATH II/EL      FORTUNE, DOMINIC
11      RAVEN, SABBATH II/EL   ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA
12      RAVEN, SABBATH II/EL  IRON MAN/TONY STARK 
13      RAVEN, SABBATH II/EL  IRON MAN IV/JAMES R.
14      IRON MAN IV/JAMES R.      FORTUNE, DOMINIC
15      IRON MAN IV/JAMES R.   ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA
16      IRON MAN IV/JAMES R.  IRON MAN/TONY STARK 
17      IRON MAN/TONY STARK       FORTUNE, DOMINIC
18      IRON MAN/TONY STARK    ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA
19       ERWIN, CLYTEMNESTRA      FORTUNE, DOMINIC
20            PRINCESS ZANDA  BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL
21            PRINCESS ZANDA         LITTLE, ABNER
22             LITTLE, ABNER  BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL
23      BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL         LITTLE, ABNER
24      BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL        PRINCESS ZANDA
25      BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL  CARNIVORE/COUNT ANDR
26      BLACK PANTHER/T'CHAL         LITTLE, ABNER
27             LITTLE, ABNER        PRINCESS ZANDA
28             LITTLE, ABNER  CARNIVORE/COUNT ANDR
29      CARNIVORE/COUNT ANDR        PRINCESS ZANDA
                     ...                   ...
574436  CANNONBALL II/SAM GU  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE 
574437  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE                ROGUE /
574438  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE               CALIBAN/
574439  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE               CALLISTO
574440  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE   COLOSSUS II/PETER RA
574441  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE                 SELENE
574442  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE   PROFESSOR X/CHARLES 
574443  WASP/JANET VAN DYNE   PHOENIX III/RACHEL S
574444  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S               ROGUE /
574445  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S              CALIBAN/
574446  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S              CALLISTO
574447  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S  COLOSSUS II/PETER RA
574448  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S                SELENE
574449  PHOENIX III/RACHEL S  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES 
574450  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES                ROGUE /
574451  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES               CALIBAN/
574452  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES               CALLISTO
574453  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES   COLOSSUS II/PETER RA
574454  PROFESSOR X/CHARLES                 SELENE
574455                SELENE               ROGUE /
574456                SELENE              CALIBAN/
574457                SELENE              CALLISTO
574458                SELENE  COLOSSUS II/PETER RA
574459  COLOSSUS II/PETER RA               ROGUE /
574460  COLOSSUS II/PETER RA              CALIBAN/
574461  COLOSSUS II/PETER RA              CALLISTO
574462              CALLISTO               ROGUE /
574463              CALLISTO              CALIBAN/
574464              CALIBAN/               ROGUE /
574465  HULK/DR. ROBERT BRUC     MARKS, DR. SHIELA

[574466 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: What output *are* you getting?

Comment: Is the dataset exactly the same as the example in the book?

Comment: I edited to add my output

Comment: yes, it is. exactly the same

Comment: why did you ask 2 similar questions?

Comment: @Kikohs good question! I haven't seen it had already been answered in comment in http://stackoverflow.com/q/35294519/5050917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is a little mistake in your example code. The last line should be `graph_from_csv("hero_network.csv")` (instead of `data` which is a `DataFrame`) ?

This explains the `TypeError` output (because you later try to use the `open()` using this DataFrame as an argument where the function is expecting the path to the file as a string).

```
def graph_from_csv(path):
    graph = nx.Graph(name="Heroic Social Network")
    with open(path, 'rU') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        for row in reader:
            graph.add_edge(*row)
    return graph.size()

graph_from_csv("hero-network.csv")

Out[15]: 167219
```